# How to upload image with Jodit uploader and coldfusion?

Tags: javascript, typescript, coldfusion, image-uploading, jodit

I'm using [Jodit](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/) to create a wysiwyg editor.  I have a coldfusion file (uploadimage2.cfm) that is empty. When I send the uploaded img to that empty coldfusion page I get an error that coldfusion can't find the variable "FILES".

Jodit is sending the following form data to uploadimage2.cfm:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryIrkl9oNQedwACmBe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"


------WebKitFormBoundaryIrkl9oNQedwACmBe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"

default
------WebKitFormBoundaryIrkl9oNQedwACmBe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]"; filename="HandShake.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryIrkl9oNQedwACmBe--
```

It seems coldfusion is getting stuck on the name="files[0]" part.  I have a working upload function that doesn't use Jodit and it sends name="image" in place of it.

I have not been able to intercept the form data to try to rename it when Jodit sends it.

Here's my javascript with the Jodit plugin:

```
var editor = new Jodit('#newEditor',
   uploader: {
        url: "uploadimage2.cfm",
        filesVariableName: "image"
   }
);
```

How can I send the correct form data for coldfusion to not throw errors?

Comment: If your `uploadimage2.cfm` is truly "empty", then the error happens at a different spot. Check the stacktrace, there seems to be a file/event that is invoked before `uploadimage2.cfm` is hit, e.g. `Application.cfm` or `onRequestStart` in `Application.cfc`.

Comment: 1. You can use the [`prepareData`](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/Jodit.defaultOptions.html#uploader) callback for manipulating the data. 2. As the `files` is an array so you can't directly access it from CF. Variables `files[0], files[1]` and so on would be available.

Comment: @Beginner I tried the prepare data callback but the form data that it generates is empty. I tried to populate it with the input value but for some reason that is empty too.

Comment: @Alex I will check the application.cfc file. I'm not sure why it would fail with jodits ajax call but not any of my own

Comment: @Alex ...yup the problem was in application.cfc it was trying to evaluate form fieldnames to strip potential malicious scripting and it thought the files[0] was an array object that it couldn't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I figured out that my problem was in my `application.cfc` file. The `onRequest` function was trying to evaluate `"files[0]"` in order to make sure there was no script injection in it. This was used for other form text uploads.

Here's how I got the Jodit upload to work with coldfusion in it's entirety:

My uploadimage2.cfm file:

```
<!--- set content type to json so jodit can read the response --->
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">

<!--- create a structure with necessary objects --->
<cfset responseStruct = structNew()>
<cfset responseStruct["message"] = "File was uploaded">
<cfset responseStruct["error"] = 0>
<cfset responseStruct["path"] = "#application.image_root#">
<cfset responseStruct["images"] = []>

<cfset variables.mediapath="#application.image_upload_root#\">

<!--- loop over the form data to upload each image individually --->
<cfloop collection="#form#" item="i">
    <cfif findNoCase("files",i) gte 1>
         <cffile action="upload"
            fileField="#i#"
            destination="#variables.mediapath#"
            accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/svg+xml"
            nameconflict="makeunique"
            result="this_image">

        <cfscript>arrayAppend(responseStruct["images"],"#this_image.serverFile#");</cfscript> 
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<!--- serialize the structure to json --->    
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(responseStruct)#</cfoutput>
```

Then in my Jodit initialization:

```
var editor = new Jodit('#editor',
    {
       uploader: {
            url: "uploadimage2.cfm",
                isSuccess: function (resp) {
                //this step is necessary for whatever reason, otherwise it will throw an error.
                    return resp;
                },
                process: function(resp){
                    //this was an important step to align the json with what jodit expects.
                    return {
                        files: resp.images,
                        path: resp.path,
                        baseurl: resp.path,
                        error: resp.error,
                        message: resp.message
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
```